# Angularjs does not update the data retrieved from the $http service

Tags: json, angularjs, pagination, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a service using Angularjs. Initially, I want to just show the first 10 elements. Then, when the user clicks on a button (with ng-click="next()"), I want the same function to be triggered again in order to get the next 10 elements.

Here's my controller:

```
Admin.controller('orders', function ($scope, $http) {

var startIndex = 0;
const count = 10;

function retrieveData(startIndex, count) {
    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Admin/order/GetOrders',
            data: { "startIndex": startIndex, "count": count }
            })
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.orders = data;
                startIndex = startIndex + count;
                $scope.$apply();
            });
};

retrieveData(startIndex, count);

$scope.next = retrieveData(startIndex, count);

};
```

Now, what happens is that the function retrieveData() works perfectly the first time, but when I click the button nothing happens. I know for sure that the "click" event triggers the function, because I tried to replace the code with an alert, but I don't understand why the function retrieveData() itself only works the first time.

What am I missing?

```
<div class="container admin" ng-controller="orders">
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="order in orders| filter:{OrderStatus: 'Hto'} | filter:query | filter:'!'+showCancelled | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
            <td>
                {{order.UserName}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <span ng-class="{ 'label label-danger' : isLate }">
                    {{order.OrderDate}}
                </span>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{order.Country}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <span ng-class="{ 'label label-warning' : order.OrderStatus == 'HtoPreAuth' || order.OrderStatus == 'SalePreAuth'}">
                    {{order.OrderStatus}}
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a href="" ng-click="retrieveData()">
    next
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried it without the `$scope.$apply()` call?

Comment: You're most likely calling the function incorrectly from your markup. Show the ng-click please.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? To play it safe you should check if digest is in progress before calling $scope.$apply()

Comment: You are not returning anything from `retrieveData`, so `$scope.next` should be `undefined`.

Comment: I tried removing $scope.$apply(); because I got the error "$rootScope:inprog Action Already In Progress" in the console. But it's still not updating the data after the click on the button. The markup of the button is 
<a href="" ng-click="next()">
    next
</a>. And yes, the $scope.next is null. What should I do??

Comment: Maybe you should post the view code too.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to make the changes inside the $apply method:

```
Admin.controller('orders', function ($scope, $http) {

    var startIndex = 0;
    const count = 10;


    $scope.retrieveData() { // No parameters
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Admin/order/GetOrders',
            data: { "startIndex": startIndex, "count": count }
        })
        .success(function (data) {
            startIndex = startIndex + count;
            $scope.orders = data;

            if(!$scope.$$phase) {
                $scope.$digest();
            }
        });
    }

    $scope.retrieveData();
};


// And the view
<a ng-click="retrieveData()"></a>
```

Edit:

Remove the parameters from the $scope.retrieveData function since they will be undefined
if you call the function with ng-click="retrieveData()"

Comment: I've edited my answer. Replace the contents of the request callback with that and you should be good.

Comment: Mm... this way it seems not to get data at all. I'm going nuuuts.

Comment: If you used all the code from my answer be sure to also replace the ng-click="next()" with ng-click="retrieveData()"

Comment: The $scope.retrieveData function should not have parameters or you must provide the params when calling ng-click="retrieveData(startIndex, count)"

Comment: Sorry man but it still doesn't work. Of course I replaced ng-click="next()" with ng-click="retrieveData()", and I also tried removing the parameters, or keeping the parameters passing them from the view with ng-click="retrieveData(startIndex, count)". Nothing did the trick.